# Runtime error when iterating over cells in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, openoffice-calc, infinite-loop

I have a table where the values are very large, in order of millions. Basically I want to iterate through all the cells(In a particular column) and divide each of them by some number (like 10,00,000).

But the thing is I do not want the output in one place, rather the cells have to be updated with this normalized value. I do not know any of the BASIC languages used by Calc for its macros.

Any help in how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:==>** I attempted to make a macro using the link provided by DavidPostill

```
   REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Sub Main

Dim i as Long

For i = 3 To Rows.Count
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
    Cells(i, 3).Divide(100000) = Cells(i,3)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

But it results to an error :-

> BASIC runtime error. Object variable not set

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know the BASIC language required to write such code and there are no examples demonstrating anything like this....

Comment: Time to start learning then. [Loop through Entire Column in Excel VBA - Easy Excel Macros](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-entire-column.html) will get you started ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why @DavidPostill posted a link about Excel VBA, because your question is about LibreOffice Basic, which is significantly different. That's why the error occurs.

A good place to start for LibreOffice macros is http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php. Chapter 6 is about Calc. Look at sections *6.5.1. Simple example processing selected cells* and *6.14 Display all data in a column*.

Comment: I did not need to learn Calc macros because I made a simple script in Matlab (Which is where I was for this project). But since this is the only answer, I will mark it as the accepted one.